# Convert vb code to c# / bool

Tags: c#

Hhe code create inside a class .
How do I convert this to c# code ?

vb code :

```
Public Shared HBitEnable(16) As Boolean
```

my code in c#

```
public static bool HBitEnable(16)
```

error

> "Type expected"

Comment: What is for `(16)` part? Is this a field definition or a local variable?

Comment: i think it is a local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your VB code is actually declaring an *array* and initializing it - not declaring a method. (It's not a local variable - it's a public static field.) So the equivalent in C# would be:

```
public static bool[] HBitEnable = new bool[17];
```

Note the use of 17 rather than 16, as VB array initialization states the maximum valid index, not the length of the array.

I would strongly advise against the use of public static fields anyway, mind you.